# <a> in header: only part of it works?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[My site](http://jonnyt.netai.net/) is being developed on WordPress and the Thematic theme framework, and I'm having an issue inside the header. When you hover over my name in the header, it should all be a link to the homepage.

However, that's not the case. Between the A and N in "Jonathan," the  randomly stops working. Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the changes below, i deleted some of the codes, i hope i did not forget anything.

```
.menu-home-container {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
    }
#navigation {
  float: right;
}
.menu {
    line-height: 44px;
    margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm...this one seems to be a likely candidate for a solution. I'll redo some of my styles to try to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your menu links are too wide - their containing box overlaps your logo.

Lower it's width, and you should be good to go.

**Details:**

...wp-content/themes/thematic/library/layouts/2c-r-fixed.css

in that CSS file, the `.menu` has a width of `940px`;

**Edit:**

Along with lowering it's width, increase `.menu-home-container`'s `margin-left` (currently around 30? - I forget) to ~`200px`

Comment: I've tried lowering it until the links were ready to go onto two lines. It didn't work. Thank you though!

Comment: Updated my answer and tested - increasing that margin-left moves it further right, which keeps it from overlapping your logo.  Obviously you could edit it further to be float:right or something instead of increasing the margin - but - this is a quick/easy fix for the time being.

Comment: Oh...so the Thematic parent theme has a built-in `.menu` style? I'll see if I can fix it within the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ul.menu`.

It is overlapping your name.

**EDIT**

On closer inspection, it is a `float:left;` in your `#blog-title` that is tripping you up.  Change it to `display:inline-block;` and all should be good.

```
#blog-title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

*This keeps it in the document flow*

Comment: Tried it just now...sends the menu onto a line slightly lower than and to the left from the name. Thank you though!

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! With a little extra tweak (negative `margin-top`), I got it back in the header. Works well enough for me!

Comment: Beauty!  Glad to help @Jonathan.